# Resize div width relative to its height to keep aspect ratio

Tags: css, html, height, width

I want to keep the `.center` div's width relative to its height by `4:3` aspect ratio (4 width per 3 height) and height of `100%`; Then align center the div horizontally.

Like you can see [here](http://s1.sfgame.de/) with a flash application.

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="stuff" class="center" width="800" height="600"> 
     <canvas id="someHTML5">You cant play HTML5</canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 800px; /* how do I make this relative; i want: pseudo code: width: height/3*4; */
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -400px; /* -width/2 for horizontal alignment */
    z-index: 100;  
}
```

I have also a JavaScript loop to integrate JavaScript side updates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `width` of the box should be changed relative to its `height`, you could use `vh`  **[viewport relative length](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)** as the value of the `width` property.

From the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the `height` or `width` of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> **vh unit**
>   Equal to `1%` of the `height` of the initial containing block.

Here you go:

```css
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 133.33vh; /* 100 * 4/3 ratio */
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -66.66vh; /* width / 2 */
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9QnYw/)**.

It's worth noting that `vh`, `vw` viewport-percentage lengths [are supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

---

## Browser compatibility

[image]

<sub>Credits: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that resizes like a video.

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  resize();
};

function resize() {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  var wrapperwidth = 1920;
  var wrapperheight = 1080;
  var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  var vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
  var ratio = Math.min(vw / wrapperwidth, vh / wrapperheight);
  wrapper.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) scale(${ratio})`;
}

resize();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1919px;
  height: 1079px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

/* demo text (smiley face) */

.wrapper::after {
  content: ":)";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: "Roboto", 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```